# vb.net debug error - database cannot be copied

Tags: vb.net, debugging, error-handling

I am trying to debug my program however, i constantly get this warning:

Could not copy "obj\x86\Debug\Sociology Revision Toolkit.exe" to "bin\Debug\Program.exe". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Program.exe' because it is being used by another process.

The program can still be ran however but this message constantly pops up. Also the program doesnt crash during runtime. Also, the database used in the program is fully accessible.

Comment: How many Projects in your solution....Perhaps one of them is trying to write to the same name as another...

Comment: What does this have to do with 'database'?

Comment: That happens from time to time in VS (it is a build issue - nothing to do with a database).  Wait a few seconds, Clean project, then rebuild, *usually* sets the matter right.

Comment: I would add to @Plutonixs sage advice and suggest you shut VS, delete all your temp files, start VS again

Comment: yes, restart if that doesnt fix it, but you cannot delete the BIN and OBJ folders if some process has something open in one of them